# Android access each child control of a parent control

Tags: android, foreach, parent-child

I need to access the children controls of a parent control. The code i am using is:

```
for (int index = 0; index <= parent.getChildCount() - 1; index++) 
{
   Log.d("myTag", parent.getChildAt(index).toString());
}
```

It works fine however i was looking for something like:

```
foreach(control ctl in parentControl.Children)
{
   Log.d("myTag", ctl.toString());
}
```

Thanks in advance for your valuable time & help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can only access the children of a view using the method `getChildAt()`, you won't be able to use it in such a foreach loop.
However, if you **really** want it, you could make a list of the children, then iterate over it this way:

```
for(View child : childs)
```

(Thats the syntaxs of `foreach` loop in java)

But it's not needed and you will be wasting time and memory doing so. Just use the `for` loop.